# Linux (Mageia): make not found /usr/bin/make

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, makefile, lazarus

I recently installed Lazarus 1.0.12 on Mageia Linux Operating System. While in the middle of bring back everything to where It was, before my computer crashed. I am running into this error which I have never seen before.

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

I found some solutions online, but they all pointed me to the fact that I need to set the correct make path within Option->>Environment->>File->>Make to /usr/bin/make

I did make the change, but it still raises same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/make` exist in your system?

Comment: It doesn't. Sorry. I forgot to mention it. So, where can you find it or how would you install it?

Comment: It probably is provided by some package named `make`

Comment: @ThayananthanNarayanan Please read [How to use Megeia package manager](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Software_management)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comment made by the asker, `/usr/bin/make` does not exist, so we need to install `make` first.

Try this:

```
urpmi make
```

This requires root privilege.

See [URPMI](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/URPMI) and [Software management](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Software_management).